# For what value of $k$ does $|x-2|<k \Rightarrow x>0$

Tags: inequality

Given the set :

$$E=\{ x \in \mathbb R \ : \  |x-2| < k \} \text{ for some } k$$

For what values of $k$ is $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^+$ ? That is, for what values of $k$ do we  have $x>0$

Comment: $|x-2|$ measure the distance of $x$ from $2$. So what is the maximum/upper bound on the distance from $2$ such that $x$ is positive?

Answer (score 1):

$$|x-2|<k\quad\iff\quad-k<x-2<2\quad\iff\quad 2-k<x<4$$
So  $\;|x-2|<k$ implies $x>0$ for $0\leq k<2$.